# pass multiple dates to foreach loop container

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a process where I want to pass multiple dates that have not been loaded to my foreach loop container to iterate through dates one at a time. if there are no start dates in the table that have been loaded I have the isnull in the where clause to tell it to start on the min date from that table. Currently if there is a date in the table that has been loaded it will grab the next calendar date from the table to process but wont loop through all the dates. My goal is to have it pass all dates that have not been loaded and iterate through each date one at a time. So what I would like to do is to take the min and max date from ods.CalendarDate and load everything between those dates and including those dates that has not been loaded to dbo.Customerinformation. Below is my query at the moment, please help me right this to where it will select all the dates that have not been processed from the table. Thank you

```
    DECLARE @ProcessAllDataSet BIT = ?
    DECLARE @StartDate Date =?
    DECLARE @EndDate date = ?

   IF @LoadFullDataSet = 1
      BEGIN 
      SELECT @StartDate = MIN(StartDate),
         @EndDate = Max(StartDate) FROM dbo.CustomerInformation 
        END 

      SELECT DateProcessed = MIN(DateCalendar)
      FROM ods.CalendarDate c
      WHERE c.CalendarDate > ISNULL(@EndDate,'2001-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close. I'm assuming `ods.CalendarDate` is a table of calendar dates. If so, just modify your query to return all the dates between your @StartDate and @EndDate. Make sure you set your `ResultSet` property of the `Execute SQL Task` to `Full Result Set` and map the results to an Object-type SSIS variable.

```
DECLARE @ProcessAllDataSet BIT = ?
DECLARE @StartDate Date =?
DECLARE @EndDate date = ?

IF @ProcessAllDataSet = 1
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        @StartDate = MIN(StartDate),
        @EndDate = Max(StartDate) 
    FROM dbo.CustomerInformation 
END 

SELECT 
    DateProcessed = DateCalendar
FROM ods.CalendarDate c
WHERE c.CalendarDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate,'2001-01-01') AND ISNULL(@EndDate,'2100-01-01')
```

Then set your `Foreach Loop` to use the `Foreach ADO Enumerator` and use your Object variable as the `ADO object source variable`. Map the `DateProcessed` field to a Date variable and then you can use that Date variable as you iterate through process.